# How can I know when my client login to my app from differnt device

Tags: php, laravel, security, networking

I am working on how can I know my client change their device when they login to my app, I am using Laravel framework so I was used `$ip = $request->ip();` to get an IP address, it's not working as I need, it's become when user login from the different IP address as you know when I connect/disconnect IP address change, so my question how can I detect user device I know there is no way to get a mac address of my client device.

login.php

```php
  public function login()
  {
       //..

       auth()->user()->update(['trusted_device' => request()->ip()]);

       //..
  }
```

Comment: Check `USER-AGENT` you get info like: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent and of course you can get Screen Size, Pixel Dept/Resolution etc.

Comment: @Cyborg thank you, I think it will solve my issue.

Comment: You are most welcome, if it solves your issue then please mark this question as solved. If still need more info then also let know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check **`USER-AGENT`**, try:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

To see some more info try:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```